# LiveData after observer is being called, how can I send 2 sets of values?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-livedata

I am recently shifting my code to the mvvm pattern with livedata and am having few difficulties. Now I set an observer on a arraylist whose data comes from API.

Now there are 2 conditions for the api to be hit, either I get the old values or the new values. Basic condition on the api is called with param OLD/NEW. 
Now when the data is changed and the observer gets the new data, whether the data is OLD/NEW I have to perform few operation. How can I get the list and which data it is(OLD/NEW) in the observer.

Here is the observer :

```
private Observer<List<Post>> oldPostsObserver = new Observer<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Post> posts) {
            if (posts != null && posts.size() > 0)
                setPostRecyclerView(posts, OLD/NEW);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why don't you send this flag as a parameter in your `onChanged` method? Like `Pair<List<Post>, Boolean>` where `boolean` stands for OLD/NEW.

Comment: Is there any code i can refer?